# ReactJS: I have a click handler that is skipping the first props method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

var mode=[ 'recent', 'alltime'];

class Header extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
     super()
   }

   render(){
     return <h2>Free Code Camp Leader board</h2>
   }
}


class Leader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       users: [],
       val: props.m
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({val: props.m})
    this.ajax();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.ajax(); 
  }

  ajax(){
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/"+this.state.val)
           .then((result) => {
             console.log(result.data);
             var leaders = result.data;
             this.setState({
               users: leaders
           });
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state, this.props)
    return (
        <div className='container'>

         <div className="tbl">
           <table className="table">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Recent </th>
                 <th>Alltime</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             {this.state.users.map(function(data, index){
                return (<tr key={index}><td><img src={data.img} className="img img-thumbnail" width="50"/>{data.username}</td> 
                <td id='recent'>{data.recent}</td> 
                <td id='alltime'>{data.alltime}</td></tr>)
             })}
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </div>
      </div>
     )
   }
}


class App extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super(),
    this.state={val: mode[0]},
    this.onClick= this.onClick.bind(this)
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({val: this.state.val === mode[0]? mode[1] : mode[0]})
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className='header'>
          <Header />
          <button  onClick={this.onClick}  >{this.state.val==mode[0]? mode[1] : mode[0]}</button>
          </div>
         <div>
           <Leader m={this.state.val} />
         </div>
        </div>
     );
   }
 } 

 export default App;
```

For some reason the app loads properly, but on the first click of the button inside of  is clicked, it does nothing; however, it works just fine on subsequent clicks, aside from being out of sync with the text on the button. Is there something wrong with the use of componentWillReceiveProps method?

Comment: In `Leader`, make sure in the constructor to `.bind(this)` for the `ajax` function. Not sure if that's the problem, but it could be hiding something else.

Comment: Also, in the `constructor` of the `App` component there are some syntax errors, specifically, extra `,`. It's good practice to always put closing `;` in, even if they aren't technically needed. It will help you catch other bugs sooner.

Comment: THankyou, but does not seem to make a difference

Comment: Also might be worth reading http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're doing your AJAX and managing React state. Let's take a look:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({val: props.m})
    this.ajax();
  }
  ajax(){
    this.serverRequest = 
          axios.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/"+this.state.val)
           .then((result) => {
             console.log(result.data);
             var leaders = result.data;
             this.setState({
               users: leaders
           });
      });
  }
```

Let's walk through what happens here:

1. The component receives a new prop value. `componentWillReceiveProps` is called.
2. Inside `componentwillReceiveProps` the first thing that happens is you call `setState`. Which is fine... except that `state` won't update until *after `componentWillReceiveProps` completely finishes running.* From [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

So for the moment this does nothing - `state` remains exactly as it is for the time being; it has an outdated value! I'm not sure if it's explicitly documented but as far as I know, the *only* reliable place to access `state` after a `this.setState` is in the `render()` function.

3. `this.ajax()` is called. Inside `ajax()` is an `axios.get()` call. Notice here how you're formatting a URL with `this.state.val` in it. At this point the component `state` has still not updated, so you're sending a GET request to the wrong URL.
4. `ajax()` finishes running, and so does `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Sometime after this point is when `state`will *actually* update. But, you've already initiated an AJAX call with the wrong URL, so it's too late now!

In a nutshell: `this.setState` does not update `state` right away and that's your problem. You're always seeing a result from AJAX that's "one state" too old.

**How to fix it**

It's easy actually. Instead of `ajax` relying on whatever `this.state.val` is at the moment it is called, rewrite it to accept it as a parameter.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({val: props.m})
    this.ajax(props.m);
  }
  // You have to modify componentWillMount() too because it should pass a parameter
  // No need to access state though - just use the prop directly
  componentWillMount() {
      this.ajax(this.props.val); 
  }
  // ajax() now accept a parameter it will use to construct its URL
  ajax(value){
    this.serverRequest = 
          axios.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/"+value)
           .then((result) => {
             console.log(result.data);
             var leaders = result.data;
             this.setState({
               users: leaders
           });
      });
  }
```

**Other notes**

It's very weird of you to be taking in changing `props` and then for some reason transferring them to `state`. You can just use `props` directly, and whenever they change, use `componentWillReceiveProps()` do do your AJAX calls or whatever.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it! Thanks for a well thought out response, I've learned a good bit about handling ajax calls in react.

Answer (score 2):

First, `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be called when the component is mounted. Check the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/componentWillReceiveProps-not-triggered-after-mounting.html). Therefore, you should call the first `ajax` call in `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount(){
this.setState({val: this.props.m},this.ajax);
 }
```

Second, you should be aware that `setState` method is async. In your `componentWillReceiveProps`, you should call `this.ajax` method as a callback of `this.setState` method to make sure your `this.state.val` already updated when calling the `ajax`.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({val: nextProps.m},this.ajax);
  }
```

One more thing, make sure that `ajax` method is bind to your component instance.

Comment: Thankyou, I sometimes forget that you can add additional callback arguments with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

the componentWillReceiveProps method is designed not to run on first mount since this method focuses on comparing the new props with the old props. Maybe that is the one causing the problem.